# typeorm synchronize is not working in React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite, typeorm, react-native-sqlite-storage

i am writing app using react-native, with typeorm+sqlite as the main data storage.
the typeorm is initialized successfully as expected if there is no database yet.
but once the database is created, the error appears every time I initialize the dataSource

```
const dataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'react-native',
    database: '3.db',
    logging: false,
    entities: [
      LocalFields
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    location: 'default',
  });
```

```
{ [E: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO "temporary_LocalFields"() SELECT  FROM "LocalFields"]
  query: 'INSERT INTO "temporary_LocalFields"() SELECT  FROM "LocalFields"',
  parameters: undefined,
  driverError:
   { message: 'near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO "temporary_LocalFields"() SELECT  FROM "LocalFields"',
     code: 0 },
  code: 0,
  line: 66,
  column: 331,
  sourceURL: '/data/user/0/com.ctf_omniwe_kiosk/files/CodePush/2ad235823c055e7bbea04b7dfaab7ff06dce0b41710ebf1de87002d81de23d29/CodePush/index.android.bundle' }
```

my versions are

- "react-native": "0.66.3",
- "typeorm": "0.3.9"
- "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",

Please, can someone provide me with some solutions or suggestions?